# Adding namespace prefix to child nodes problem

Tags: xml, xslt

Actually as i see i can add name spaces. Because I am very close to output i expect to see. First codes:

XML:

```
<helptext>
    <h6>General configuration options.</h6>
    <h2>Changing not yet supported.</h2>
    <p>this is a <b>paragraph</b><br/>this is a new line</p>
</helptext>
```

XSL:

```
<xsl:template name="transformHelptext">
    <xsl:for-each select="./child::*">
        <xsl:element name="ht:{local-name()}">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="count(./child::*)>0">
                    <xsl:call-template name="transformHelptext"/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

So far so good. There are no problems for `<h6>..</h6>` and `<h2>...</h2>` lines.
But third line has child node which is a `<b>`. And somehow "paragraph" is the only text  which is displayed, for this line. I have a mistake in `choose` statement. But I cannot figure it out.

Thanks

P.S : ht namespace is defined in xsl-stylesheet tag and it is 'xmlns:ht="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"'

P.S : What I try to do is, making it possible to apply html tags, styles on my specific xml nodes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this instead:

```
<xsl:template name="transformHelptext">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"  />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*" >
    <xsl:element name="ht:{local-name(.)}">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"  />
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@*|text()" >
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"  />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Inside the "transformHelptext" templeate, select all attributes and nodes and apply templates to them.

The second template matches element nodes and changes the namespace. The third template match attributes and text nodes and just creates a copy.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But it does show just plain text unless browser is firefox.

Comment: @savruk maybe the xml headers are missing

Comment: Norman: If you go this way, then there is no need for apply templates to unexistent attributes or child nodes of attributes or text nodes. Just use `xsl:copy-of select="."` or even `xsl:copy` as content template. Do note that there could be comments and processing instructions as well.

Answer (score 1):

**Input XML :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<helptext>
   <h6>General configuration options.</h6>
   <h2>Changing not yet supported.</h2>
   <p>this is a <b>paragraph</b><br/>this is a new line</p>
</helptext>
```

**XSLT:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="*|@*">
    <xsl:element name="ht:{local-name()}" namespace="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

**Output XML :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ht:helptext xmlns:ht="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <ht:h6>General configuration options.</ht:h6>
    <ht:h2>Changing not yet supported.</ht:h2>
    <ht:p>
       this is a
       <ht:b>paragraph</ht:b>
       <ht:br />
       this is a new line
    </ht:p>
</ht:helptext>
```

**Discussion :**
  As much as possible, avoid using `<xsl:for-each>` as it can slow down the processor.